# Oracle's SQL how to convert the date's format

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

this is my table:

table name `EXAMPLE`
column name `DATE`

this is the output for the following query:

```
SELECT date 
  FROM example;

1/23/2010
```

I want to convert the output to:

```
23-Jan-10
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use formatting along with `TO_CHAR()` conversion such as

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'DD-Mon-RR') 
  FROM example
```

where

- `DATE` is not a good name for a column as being a reserved keyword. So, I've replaced it with `dt`

Comment: @Barbaros thanks for good edits. It helped alot

Comment: mostly i use YY , didnt know RR is also an alternative. currently i am reading it :)

Comment: The RR format was meant to be a temporary expedient in resolving the Y2K issue -- and that was over twenty years ago.  Oracle uses it as a default, for backward compatibility on a huge base of customer-installed code.  That said, there is no good reason to continue using it at this point.    And another lesson from Y2k is that you should always use 4-digit years -- YYYY.  I spent far too much time on this in 1998-1999 to just sit by and watch it all get undone now.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is in `varchar/text..` then you can first convert to date then back to char

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR( 
to_date('1/23/2010','mm/dd/yyyy'),'DD-Mon-YY'
) 
datec FROM dual;
```

If it is in date format, `to_char` only will do

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(date_column, 'DD-Mon-YY' ) 
datec FROM dual;
```

Comment: _"If your column is in varchar/text.."_, then you have a very serious design flaw ....

Comment: It is possible in many cases to have date recorded as number or varchar. for example `20210923`. YYYYMMDD . Its not a serious design flow. depends on how you have agreed to interact with other systems. i encounter this many times in many systems.

Comment: If you store a date as anything but DATE, you have no integrity, and you cannot do true date comparisons or date arithmetic.  If you define it as varchar2, there is nothing to prevent a 'date' of 'yadayadayada'.  And if you define it as a number there is is nothing to prevent a value of 0  or 99.  If this presents issues with interfacing with other systems, then take care of the problem at the interface.  Encountering it in "many" systems does not make it a valid practice. It just means the designers of those systems were equally clueless.

Comment: I agree, but it always depends. one maybe loading records from a flatfile to a staging table. now the staging table could have all columns as text so as not to loose any record,  then do a clean up to a well structured table.

Answer (score 0):

A `DATE` data type is a binary format that is stored in 7-bytes that has no format and always contains the components: year (stored as century and year-of-century), month, day, hour, minute and second.

Therefore, you cannot change the format of a `DATE` data type.

If instead, you ask the question:

> How can format a `DATE` to output it as `23-Jan-10`?

Then you can convert the `DATE` to a formatted string using the `TO_CHAR` function:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
         AS formatted_date
FROM   your_table;
```

Alternatively, if you want the output as a `DATE` data type then you can use:

```sql
SELECT your_date_column
FROM   your_table;
```

and change the user interface (SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, PLSQLDeveloper, PHP, Java, etc.) you are using to alter how that that user interface displays dates. The solution is going to depend on which user interface you are using but for SQL/Plus and SQL Developer, you can change Oracle's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY';
```

Other user interfaces will have different solutions specific to those interfaces.